# Android: Making changes to a button's parent view

Tags: android, view, parent

I have a RelativeLayout with a button inside it. Once the user clicks on that button, I would like to change the background of the parent view (RelativeLayout). I know I can do this by storing the parent view in a variable or setting a tag on the button, but I'd lime to avoid that (I have very good reasons for not wanting this). Isn't there a way to just access the parent view from the button itself?

Comment: What's wrong with using getParent()?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try [`View.getParent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29):

```
Button yourBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn);
RelativeLayout yourRelLay = (RelativeLayout) yourBtn.getParent();
```

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but I didn't realize that you can cast .getParent() to the view that you want. I'll see if that works

Comment: I knew that the ViewParent was the base class, but it didn't even occur to me that i could cast it to the type of parent. What a fool! Thanks Floern.